# How can I turn part of the Excel data to columns to get a desired output?

Tags: excel, rows, transpose, data-cleaning

For eg - Say I have data in the following format -

***Current Format***
[image]

I would need the data to be formatted in the following format for ease of use -

***Required Format***
[image]

Of course the data contains a lot more records - I'm looking for an easy way to transpose data in this way for large sets of data.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy with PowerQuery. It is inbuilt for Excel 2016 and a freely available add in for Version from 2010 to 2013.

You would set your data up as a table excluding the first row which contains the text Number of Cases (Ctrl + T whilst bring up window to create table)

[image: Create table]

Then from the data tab (Excel 2016) or the Powerquery tab (earlier versions) select data from table and use your newly created table as source.

Highlight the last 3 columns and right click > unpivot columns

[image: Unpivot]

Double click in headers section and rename Attribute as Type and Value as Number of Cases

[image: Rename headers]

Top left select close and load to

[image: Close and load to]

Select table and load to new worksheet (or existing)

[image: Load to]

View result

[image]

Comment: As you add rows to your table you can simply click on the green circling arrow next to the query to refresh the output table.

Comment: What if i have more than one measure, say cost for Type A ,B , C in a similar format?
And I need the data for cost in a new column alongside No of Cases for each Type

Comment: You would need to add an additional couple of steps to the query. I expect you will get Type A2 on initial import, as Type A exists already (and B and C). When you unpivot you can use the Find and Replace functionality to change A2 to A etc.....

Comment: @QHarr - aww, back in the old days. I just referred a new question here and was like "who was that jerk posting the same answer as me?" ...I see I beat you by 5 minutes and 14 seconds.  Also your answer may be accepted but mine's scored higher,  (...but I'm not competitive either)    :-)

Comment: @QHarr - I missed nothing.  You over-complicated, and otherwise simple task.  ...oh and I'd like to introduce a little friend: the **Crop** button in MS Paint. ‎

Comment: @QHarr *"Close, accepting changes"*, makes sense to me.  But I guess you're right - I need to remember that folks from your generation need a lot  more hand-holding since computers can be intimidating.  Maybe I'll add an animation for you.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on the pop-up book version.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is called:

### Unpivot:

1. Select the data and on the `Insert` menu choose `Table`
2. On the `Data` menu click `From Table/Range`
3. The query window will open.  Choose the columns you need to extract. With your data the columns to highlight are "***Type***" and "***Number of Cases***"
4. On the `Tranform` menu choose `Unpivot Columns`
5. If the data looks right now, close the Query Editor (accepting changes).

**Examples here**: [Unpivot Excel Data](https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/)

[image: img]