# User defined concatenate

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, powerquery, unpivot

I am trying to expand my annual planning document to give me more information. Currently however I am stuck.

My current Sheet is laid out as follows:
[image: Client Example image]

I need to create a second sheet that concatenates the client name with each column heading there is a "yes" value in, as its own separate line.

**Example 1** in the new sheet would become:

> ```
> Example 1 - Annuals
> Example 1 - Xero Fee
> ```

I had tried a copy and paste Macro, based on a quantity column counting the rows that include text. This gave the desired amount of client names in a new sheet but I was unable to work out how to include the "concatenate" part of this problem to it.

```
Public Sub CopyData()

    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Integer

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Range("G1", Range("G1").End(xlDown))

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
        ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
        If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
            ' Check if the number is greater than 0
            If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
                ' Copy this row as many times as .value
                For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                    ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2
                    Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    ' The above line finds the next empty row.

                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This can be accomplished much easier **without** VBA unless there is a specific reason you _need_ to use VBA rather than a built-in feature?  `Unpivot`comes to mind, although simple formulas using relative vs. absolute $cell $references would get the same thing done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have no preference to VBA just thought that would have been easiest to have it complete the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If your goal is to get from *this*:

[image: unpivot1]

### ...to *this* (or *that*):

[image: unpivot2]

### ...then what you want to do is called an **Unpivot**.

---

## How to Unpivot "crosstab-style" data:

[image: UnPivot demo]

You can find the steps written out on [a question I answered a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505880/8112776), and there's a more [detailed explanation and steps over here](https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/).

Let me know if you have any questions!

<sub>Yeah, maybe I used this as an excuse to practice using [Screen2Gif](http://www.screentogif.com/), but it sure helps demo a point!</sub>  **:-)**

Comment: Wow thank you that looks perfect and a lot more simpler than the route I was heading down thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  Excel has tons of handy features "hidden away" that go unused in exchange for more complicated methods, since people simply don't know about them...  Also, "Go Canada".  (the `GST` field was a giveaway!)

Comment: Hi ashleedawg. That answer worked perfectly and i have added my figures beside the names and anttributes. I found the setting so that the table updates by inserting a new row so all figures to the right shift down, Im just wondering since it is along the same line of query editor how to make it delete the whole row if table updates.

Comment: Right-click the row, choose `Delete` and `Table Rows`.   Check this out, too: [Overview of Excel tables]( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

Comment: Oh thanks for that, I must have accidentally posted that comment but thank you for the answer