# reorganizing time series data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have time series data in excel, in a format that I want to reorganize. Currently, the data has dates in rows and the times in columns, but I want the date and time in rows; thereby creating one column of data. Each time interval is 00:15 minutes. So there are 96 data points per day and 365 days of data. I want to repeat the date 96 times in column A and input each 00:15 minute interval in column B. I was thinking I could then just use an index(,match(),match()) to grab the corresponding data.

So how do I auto fill a date a certain number of times in one column, then move to the next date in the same column for the same number of times, and then end on a specific date? I think from there I can just autofill the time in the column to the right.

Is there a fix to this using a formula or simple vba macro of some sort? I am stumped!

Thank you so much!

Sara

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you don't need to play around with matches...  Excel has a built-in process called ***Unpivot*** for just this occasion.  Check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676083/8112776).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365839/excel-macrovba-to-transpose-multiple-columns-to-multiple-rows/36366394#36366394