# How to transpose varied columns in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery, unpivot

[image]

I've ton of rows like above.

Below table is ideal result.

I had worked with v-lookup, pivot table with no luck.

Is there any way to correctly match varied columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get from this:

[image: img1]

...to this:

[image: img2]

### Then what you want to do is called an *Unpivot*.

1. Highlight your data and hit **CTRL+T** to make it into a table. (Check the "my data has headings" if there are headings, or un-check it if it does not, like your example.)
2. On the **DATA** tab click **FROM TABLE/RANGE**.  This will open PowerQuery.
3. You need to select all columns EXCEPT for the first one, so click the 2nd column and then push and hold `CTRL` while you click each of the others to the right of it.
4. on the **TRANSFORM** tab click **UNPIVOT COLUMNS**.
5. Click the **X** in the top-right of the screen, and click "**KEEP CHANGES**"

*You're Done!*  (...so easy that it's fun!)

[image]

- More example and links to more detailed information at my other answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676083/8112776).

Comment: Yes, that is simpler. Would it work in Google Sheets (though I suspect there one can do a nice solution with arrayformula, transpose, textjoin, and split)?

Comment: @JeremyKahan I'm not sure about Google Sheets.  The question was about Excel - and I don't use *Sheets* and I don't know why anyone would, considering the fact that [students](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/education/products/office/default.aspx) and [developers](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program) can get  a full (unlimited; not trial) subscription to Office 365 for free (which covers pretty much anyone on this site!)  Also, the fact that nobody says "I wonder if Excel can do that too?" ... Also, I'm a little biased.. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. It's a neat trick that nobody knows, so pass it on to others!  There's lots of things that most people don't realize Excel can do automatically, such as removing duplicate data, organizing data any-which-way you can think of, consolidating multiple sheets, and automatically writing code for you. Just for the heck of it, here's a couple **favourite resources worth bookmarking: [Chip Pearson's site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) and [Ron de Bruin's site](https://www.rondebruin.nl/tips.htm) and [Free Excel Stuff](http://www.kubiszyn.co.uk/free-stuff.html)**

Comment: @ashleedawg, I'm not one of those people who gets into loyalty issues and will go on at length about Mac vs Pc, etcetera. I do find myself looking at a number of posts about excel and saying, "this would be so simple if I could use a function like..." (TEXTJOIN, ARRAYFORMULA, UNIQUE, QUERY). I'm sure there are tradeoffs, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done. Here is a vba-less approach. I am using two working columns, A and B (but these could be tucked away elsewhere and hidden). My entries start somewhere below your data lines, in my case on line 6, where in A6 through D6 I put column headers:

```
sourceline    sourcecol    country    city
```

Now in A7 I put the number 1 to say start in the first row.
In A8 I put the following formula which I dragged down as far as needed.
`=if(1+countif(indirect("A7:A"&(row()-1)),A7)=(counta(indirect("A"&A7&":Z"&A7))),A7+1,A7)`. What does it do? Well, it says let us see how many times the number right above me has occurred. If it is the same as the number of cities (assumed <=25) in the corresponding row, it is time to add 1 and move on to the next row. Otherwise, keep going with that same row.

In B7 I put the following formula and dragged it on down. `=if(A7=A6,1+B6,2)` It says, If I am still in the same row as the preceding entry, move over a column, else restart at column 2 (B).

Once I have the row and the column, for the country I needed the following in C7 and dragged down `=indirect(address(A7,1))` which says find me the value in the row mentioned here and column 1 (A).

Similarly in D7 and dragged on down I have `=indirect(address(A7,B7))` to get the city. That produces your desired table (maybe two columns over, but you could adjust that).

By leaving at least one blank line between the inputs and the headers of my outputs, you also end up with blanks at the bottom of the table if you drag your formula a bit beyond where it is needed.

You could probably simplify the formulas a smidge using the OFFSET function.