# Large table to be transformed by moving 200+ columns to rows

Tags: excel, pivot

Given a relative massive table I have recieved which is (currently) in excel. 25k rows and 225 columns.
First column is "event_Id", 2nd "organizer" 3rd-225 "participants".

I would like to transfer it to 3 columns from the 225, where event_Id and organizer can repeat, but the participant columns I would like to pivot into one column, though I have no idea how. Pulling it column by column to the pivot table columns does not feel to effective, especially if I need to repeat the process somehow.

current:

```
id1 organizer1 partic1 partic2 partic3 partic4
id2 organizer4 partic5 partic2 partic6
```

desired:

```
id1 organizer1 partic1
id1 organizer1 partic2
id1 organizer1 partic3
id1 organizer1 partic4
id2 organizer4 partic5
id2 organizer4 partic2
id2 organizer4 partic6
```

any idea is welcome- dont need to stick to excell- can go to sql, tableau...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unpivot Excel Table

What you're looking to do is called an ***UnPivot*** an takes about a dozen clicks.

[image: img]

For detailed steps and more information, see my existing answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672099/user-defined-concatenate/47676083#47676083) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51511312/8112776) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505648/how-can-i-turn-part-of-the-excel-data-to-columns-to-get-a-desired-output/47505880#47505880) and further info [here](https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/).