# In Excel, how to identify matching data in order to report shared quantities?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I have a list of products where I report which manufacturing facility *currently* makes it, as well as the QTY I need to make. Separately, I have a list that tells me ALL facilities that are equipped to manufacture that product.

What I'm looking to do is make a report that can show me, at a glance, how much work is available to offload from one facility to another.

**Current Manufacturer Builds**

```
  Product  ||  MFGR  ||  QTY to Build
     A     ||   1    ||      100
     B     ||   2    ||      50
     C     ||   3    ||      100
```

**All Product/Manufacturer Combos**

```
  Product  ||  MFGR
     A     ||   1
     A     ||   2
     B     ||   2
     B     ||   3
     C     ||   3
```

So, from the above lists we can infer:

- Product A can be made at either facility 1 or 2, but it's currently set to build at facility 1
- Product B can be made at either facility 2 or 3, but it's currently set to build at facility 2
- product C can only be made at facility 3

From all this, I would like to have a report that shows the following information:

```
  From MFGR  ||  To MFGR  ||  Avail QTY
      1      ||     2     ||     100
      1      ||     3     ||      0
      2      ||     1     ||      0
      2      ||     3     ||     50
      3      ||     1     ||      0
      3      ||     2     ||      0
```

Where, in this report, it recognizes that:

- Product A's build QTY ***CAN*** be offloaded from facility 1 to 2, so it reports a possible move of 100 from 1 to 2
- Product B's build QTY ***CAN*** be offloaded from facility 2 to 3, so it reports a possible move of 50 from 2 to 3

Note that the report ignores the product (it will need to since my actual file has 100's of products, and like 10 facilities), though I recognize it needs to take it into consideration in the formula.

Is there a single-cell formula that can get this done? I was using SUMIFS() to grab the Build QTY of the "From MFGR", but I wasn't sure how to incorporate that with anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,INDEX(E:E,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF($F$2:$F$6=I2,ROW($F$2:$F$6)*{1,1}))))),B:B,H2))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this question with detailed example, twice within the last week!

[image: unpivot]

## Detailed Instructions & More...

- Stack Overflow: [User defined concatenate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676083/8112776)
- Stack Overflow: [How can I turn part of the Excel data to columns to get a desired output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47505648/8112776)
- [Unpivot Excel Data](https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/)
- Stack Overflow: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- Stack Overflow: [How do I Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: I don't see how unpivot would work as this is two tables.  Could you please use the data above and show how you would approach the unpivot?

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't make complete sense, but I'm not looking on how to unpivot data. I need to know how to write a function that takes all QTYs that are set to be built at one manufacturing facility, and could be offloaded to another. The anchor for the data is the product.

Comment: Well it won't work with your data as-is, since Excel isn't a _mind-reader_.  I assumed you'd be using it with a complete set of data.  For example, you have 250 'qty' in the top chart and 100 fewer in the bottom.  And, why would the 100 from the first chart A1, got to A2 on the next? You can't do anything until you get clear **well tested** rules to decide what will happens in every possible situation.  **Please** read [mcve] and `how to ask`, and [edit] your question to add more detail, what have you tried, where did you search, what _specifically_ is your issue,etc.

Comment: The other answerer provided the solution to my specific issue with no additional explanation. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @mrmusaddict - I guess I was unclear on what you needed but I'm glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Just an fyi: you can get your points back by deleting the post.