# How can I use advanced filtering row wise

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

The excel file for  dates of duties taken by persons are as shown in figure. Marked duties as X

[image: pic]

How can I get the date of duties taken by a particular person using filtering?

Is there any method to get  each person's name together with their duty date in a separate sheet?

Comment: ..your goal is to display only 1 person?

Comment: @ashleedawg Ya pics are same.. I tried to delete second one but i couldn't

Comment: @ashleedawg  I need dates of duties taken by each person. For example.. I need such filter tool after filtering i get  Tessy Paul- 26 April 18,27 April 18, 30 April 18, 2-May 18 Fr. Joy PT- 26 Apr-2018 Similary for other teachers also.

Comment: Added an approach via array filtering, as IMO advanced filtering would not be sufficient - @seena

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is:

### Unpivot:

1. Select the data and on the `Insert` menu choose `Table`
2. On the `Data` menu click `From Table/Range`
3. The query window will open.  Choose the columns you need to extract. With your data the columns to highlight are "***Type***" and "***Number of Cases***"
4. On the `Tranform` menu choose `Unpivot Columns`
5. If the data looks right now, close the Query Editor (accepting changes).

---

## Another example:

### If your goal is to get from *this*:

[image: unpivot1]

### ...to *this* (or *that*):

[image: unpivot2]

### ...then what you want to do is called an **Unpivot**.

---

## How to Unpivot "crosstab-style" data:

[image: UnPivot demo]

You can find the steps written out on [a question I answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505880/8112776), and there's a more [detailed explanation and steps over here](https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/).

Comment: @ashleedwag. Sir I am not getting from table/range in Data menu

Answer (score 0):

**Approach via array filtering**

You need filter results row wise (e.g. Tessy Paul- 26 April 18, 27 April 18, 30 April 18, 2-May 18), but IMO you won't get them via *advanced filter* method. Instead I demonstrate an alternative approach using **arrays** to get the source data (looping through a range via VBA is slow) and to extract the rearranged *(=recoded)* data via **`Application.Filter`** matching items marked by **"x"** as *duty*.

**Essential steps**

First you write all your data to a variant 2-dimensioned datafield array simply by assigning a predefined range reference - see section [2]:

```
Dim v   As Variant  ' or simply: Dim v
Dim rng As Range    
'set rng = ...
v = rng.Value2  ' or simply: v = rng
```

Furthermore it's possible to filter an array via `Application.Filter` with some restrictions:

- a) you'll need some further information beyond the isolated cell data and
- b) you'll need a 1-dim array.
- ad a) In order to identify name and duty date when filtering, just add these information together with a delimiter (e.g. "#", see section [3]). 
      This allows you to split the filtered data later by looping through each array item - see sections [4] and [5].
- ad b) To get a 1-dim array out of a 2-dim array you can extract a row or a column via `Application.Index` function.
      In the example below I assign results to another array called `vi`. 
      For example: if you want to extract a row as shown in section 4.1, the second parameter identifies the row number starting from 1, the third argument *column number* simply obtains `0` :
      Then you can apply the `Filter` function with this newly dimensioned source array and a match string "x#" to get all data defined as *Duty* by the *x* character and the chosen delimiter *#*.

  vi = VBA.filter(Application.Index(v, i, 0), "x#", True, False)

**Notes:**

The match string consists of both characters ("x#"), as "x" alone could be part of a name (e.g. Alexander), too.

As an addition to row wise filtering:
To extract a column see section 5.1, as this needs an additional adjusting via `Application.Transpose`.

Each extracted row or column array will be written back to a target sheet and shown via `Join` function in `Debug.Print` in your immediate window in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE)

**Code Example**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DutiesPerName()
' Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083149/how-can-i-use-advance-filtering-row-wise
' [0] Declare variables
  Dim a()
  Dim ws    As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
  Dim rng   As Range, i As Long, j As Long, r As Long, c As Long
  Dim v, vi, temp
' [1] define sheetname and data range
' 1.0 set worksheet object to memory
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet")  ' << change to your data sheet name
  Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDutySheet") ' << change to your target sheet name
' 1.1 get rows and columns
  r = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  c = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
' 1.2 Alternative code line: Set rng = ws.UsedRange
  Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(r, c)).Address)
' [2] create a variant 1-based 2-dim datafield array
  v = rng.Value2
' [3] CODE duty items by appending "#" plus date and name info
  For i = 2 To UBound(v)                ' start loop from 2nd row
      v(i, 1) = "x#" & v(i, 1)          ' mark name captions to get them filtered, too
      For j = 3 To UBound(v, 2)         ' start inner loop from 3rd column
          If v(i, j) = "x" Then         ' code found duty items
             v(i, j) = v(i, j) & "#" & Format(v(1, j), "dd-mmm-yy") & "#" & v(i, 1) & "#" & j
             'Debug.Print "v(" & i & "," & j & ")=""" & v(i, j) & """"
          End If
      Next j
  Next i
' mark date captions with "x#" to get them filterd, too
  For j = 3 To UBound(v, 2)
        v(1, j) = "x###" & Format(Val(v(1, j)), "dd-mmm-yy")
  Next j
' -----------------------
' [4] Duty Dates per Name:
' -----------------------
  ws2.Cells.Clear: ws2.Range("A1") = "Name": ws2.Range("B1") = "Duty Dates ..."
  For i = 2 To UBound(v, 1)             ' start loop from 2nd row
  ' 4.1 filter redimensioned 1-dim ROW array via "x#"
    vi = VBA.filter(Application.Index(v, i, 0), "x#", True, False)
    For j = LBound(vi) To UBound(vi)
        vi(j) = Split(vi(j), "#")(1)    ' extracts date from e.g. "x#15-Jan-19#x#Paul#2"
    Next j
    ' write dates per name into target worksheet ws2
    ws2.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vi) + 1) = vi
    Debug.Print "Row# " & i & " (" & _
                ws2.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vi) + 1).Address & ") 1 Name + " & UBound(vi) & " Dates: " & _
                Join(vi, ", ")
   Next i
   Debug.Print
' -----------------------
' [5] Names per Duty Date:
' -----------------------
  ws2.Range("A1").Offset(r + 2, 0) = "Duty Date": ws2.Range("A1").Offset(r + 2, 1) = "Names ..."
  For i = 3 To UBound(v, 2)             ' start loop from 3rd column
  ' 5.1 filter redimensioned 1-dim COLUMN array via "x#"
    vi = VBA.filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, i)), "x#", True, False)
    For j = LBound(vi) To UBound(vi)
        temp = Split(vi(j), "#")
        vi(j) = temp(3)                  ' extracts Name from e.g. "x#15-Jan-19#x#Albert#3"
    Next j
    ' write each names per date into target worksheet ws2
    If UBound(vi) > -1 Then
       ws2.Range("A1").Offset(r + i, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vi) + 1) = vi
       Debug.Print "Col# " & i & " (" & _
                   ws2.Range("A1").Offset(r + i, 0).Resize(1, UBound(vi) + 1).Address & ") 1 Date + " & UBound(vi) & " Names: " & _
                   Join(vi, ", ")
    End If
   Next i

End Sub
```